# Script to find all network adapters I'm connected to in Python

Tags: python, network-protocols

I have a laptop that is connected to my organization's network using one or more network adapters. I'm not sure how to start this or where I should look for native python methods or other resources.

I was wondering how can I discover all the network adapters or NICs I am connected to using python. I want to try to accomplish this without a 3rd party library but if I have to that is fine as well.

I ultimately want to be able to write a tool that will continuously monitor the connectivity status and connection quality of each network. However I first have to find out which and how many network adapters I'm connected to.

Comment: Take a look here: http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2010/09/python-linux-parse-network-stats-from.html I think you need to run a command against your system to get the names of your network interfaces then parse through the data

Comment: @NicholasYoung   oooo make sense! thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`netifaces`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) would be a good start. From the [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces):

> It's been annoying me for some time that there's no easy way to get the address(es) of the machine's network interfaces from Python. [...]
>
> This package attempts to solve that problem.

Some relevant examples:

```
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo0', 'gif0', 'stf0', 'en0', 'en1', 'fw0']

>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('lo0')
{18: [{'addr': ''}],
  2: [{'peer': '127.0.0.1', 'netmask': '255.0.0.0', 'addr': '127.0.0.1'}],
 30: [{'peer': '::1', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff', 'addr': '::1'}, {'peer': '', 'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::1%lo0'}]}
```

Get it with `pip install netifaces`.

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar recently and came up with the following solution using [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/):

```
>>> import psutil

>>> psutil.net_if_addrs().keys()
dict_keys(['lo', 'eth0', 'docker0'])
```

I'm not claiming this is better, faster, more appropriate or more lightweight than the current accepted answer. I just thought it would be good to document other solutions to the problem.