# How to find just the name of ethernet network on a linux machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can we find out the name of a Ethernet port registered in a Linux machine.

For instance, when we use a `ifconfig` on the terminal , we will get a result with all the running network devices on the machine, on that we can see names like `eth0`, `wlan0` ... etc

**I am interested in finding just the name of the currently active Ethernet in my machine in a python script.**

Is there anyway we can obtain this requirement ?

Comment: There's no single "active" interface - a packet's destination depends on the routing tables, and several interfaces can be "active" at once. For example, a packet to 1.2.3.4 could go over the Wifi, 4.3.2.1 over the network cable, 6.5.34.3 to a VPN, and 127.0.0.1 via loopback. `ifconfig` gets its info by reading `/proc/net/dev` so you could do that.

Comment: As suggested by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24961413/4725649) you could use [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces)